# How to avoid files being replaced with older versions in Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

UbuntuOne for windows has replaced an OpenOffice document with an older version of the file. I am syncing between 2 windows machines and one ubuntu machine.

Fortunately I was able to recover my work from my nightly backup. Is there some kind of log file that might help me figure out what when wrong, or how to avoid this in the future?

Comment: The same problem happens with broken files I think, like truncated pictures. Should be important to investigate

Comment: Same happened to me I lost a days work. I use dropbox now. Sorry canonical.

Answer (score 1):

The main cause of this is when you save a LibreOffice file directly to your Ubuntu One folder. What happens is that LO autosaves every so often, and if that happens while you're uploading a file to U1, then you may actually have three different copies. There really is a conflict so Ubuntu keeps all of them. They're renamed to filename.u1conflict so you can look at their ages and rename them.

One "solution" is to deactivate autosave in LibreOffice. Another is to save to an unsynced folder and then copy it once in a while. I personally choose the latter though none of the approaches are perfect.  I think we would really need a Ubuntu One extension for LibreOffice for it to really work well.

Answer (score 0):

Usually UbuntuOne will backup a copy of your overwritten file with the name [filename].u1conflict, next time it happens you got [filename].u1conflict.[1-n].

I have no experience with UbuntuOne on Windows, but this is how it works with Ubuntu and Android-clients since some Ubuntu releases back.

You can monitor your UbuntuOne using the CLI-command u1stool  (u1stool -h). Maybe if you induce a replication conflict and monitor what happens, you can figure out the problem.